# Castle WCF DefaultServiceHostFactory in IIS: Accessing the ServiceHost

Tags: wcf, iis, castle, servicehost

I am attempting to move from a self hosting architecture to hosting under IIS 6, primarily to take advantage of built in dynamic compression.

I am using the Castle DefaultServiceHostFactory to provide the service to IIS in the .svc file.  However, I need to programmatically specify certain end points and behaviours and I do not know how to retrieve the current ServiceHost.

Is this be possible, or should I just look at other methods of compression independent of IIS?

Answer (score 0):

Implement `IServiceHostAware` for this.